# How can I get the icons by content query?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am modifying a background slider, but in the css:

```
span.cbp-binext:before {
content: "\e000";}
```

The only thing is that I get squares. Can I replace them with an image (.png) or is it possible to get the icons the as here in the example?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jssonline/7RCf4/) is the code.

Regards Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content:url(urltomedia);
```

Read about it there: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
content: url('you image url');
```

like

```
span.cbp-binext:before {
content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKsDb.png");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7RCf4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content